# Selecting objects based on multiple attributes QGIS

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute

I would like to select objects from the attribute table based on multiple attributes.

I want to select all ojects that have 'ja' in the column "BLAUWBORST", all objects that have 'ja' in the column "BRUINE_KIE", objects that have 'ja' in both of them and objects that have 'ja' in the column 'veertien' or 'vijftien' or...

[image]

Comment: What expression have you tried?

Comment: "BLAUWBORST" = 'ja' or "BRUINE_KIE" = 'ja' or "veertien" = 'ja' or...
But i realise that's wrong because then QGIS selects objects without looking at the BLAUWBORST or BRUINE_KIE and only to "veertien"

Comment: so you want just those rows which have 'ja' in all the rows?

Comment: No, rows that have 'ja' in BRUINE_KIE OR BLAUWBORST AND 'ja' in 'veertien' or 'vijftien' or 'zestien'

Answer (score 4):

Two options to archive this:

1. Simply connect your selection statements with a logic operator "OR" is the one you are looking for. The result is something like:

   ```
   "BLAUWBORST" = 'ja' OR "BRUINE_KIE" = 'ja' OR ...
   ```
2. Use the Add to Selection button(image 1) when you write your selecting like this

   - "BLAUWBORST" = 'ja' -> Click "select"
   - "BRUINE_KIE" = 'ja' -> click on the arrow and click "Add to selection"

[image: Image 1 where to click]

Answer (score 2):

Came across this question looking for a slightly different answer, which is to select multiple values in the same column.

I found that rather than doing a whole bunch of 'OR' statements, QGIS (as of 3.10) supports the following syntax:

`"<Column Name>" in ('<value 1>', 'value 2>')` etc.